# how do find duplicate values in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Im in trouble here; I want to collect all values from array which are duplicates.

modified Example:

```
Array [
  {
    first: array[ 24, 58],
    last:  array[ 25,     59   ]
  },
  {
    first: array[ 25, 59],
    last:  array[ 23,     57]
  },
  {
    first: array[ 25, 59],
    last:  array[ 26, 54]
  }, 
  {
    first: array[ 23, 58],
    last:  array[ 22,     58]
  }, 
  {
    first: array[ 22, 58],
    last:  array[ 23, 54]
  }, 
  Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, /*98 more…*/ ]
```

And if the script finds similar values they should be pushed to another array.

```
var arrayCollect = []
arrayCollect.push([similar values]);
```

And the result example

```
arrayCollect=[[similar values], [similar values]];
```

and similar value is an entire collection of similar values (`[Object, Object...]`)

I've tried this:

```
var array =[];
for(var i=0; i < arrayLastFirst.length; i++){
    if(arrayLastFirst[i].first[0] &&
       arrayLastFirst[i].first[1] == 
       arrayLastFirst[i].last[0]  && 
       arrayLastFirst[i].last [1]) {
          array.push(arrayLastFirst[i].first, arrayLastFirst[i].last);
    }
}
```

but that is not correct and I don't know what is wrong, I suspect incorrect logic. i modified my code for better understanding for what i want for in the end.
So my output need to be like this:

```
Array[
      [
       {
        first: array[ 24, 58],
        last:  array[ 25,59]
        },
        {
        first: array[ 25, 59],//its inside that array couse the first value is the same like the last value before that.
        last:  array[ 23,57]
        },
        {
        first: array[ 25, 59],
        last:  array[ 26, 54]
        }
       ],
       [
        {
        first: array[ 23, 58],
        last:  array[ 22,     58]
        }, 
        {
        first: array[ 22, 58],
        last:  array[ 23, 54]
        }//and these are similar values couse last and the first are the same
       ]
      ]
```

maybe this is more understandable what i need in the end.

Comment: By "similar" do you mean "the same"?

Comment: @Andy I think it means duplicate values, but you can't really directly test equality between objects, so therefore "similar".

Comment: yes, i mean "The same(duplicate values)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this data:

```
var arrayLastFirst = [
    {first: [1, 2], last: [3, 4]},
    {first: [5, 6], last: [6, 7]},
    {first: [0, 8], last: [8, 9]}
];
```

This test condition

```
arrayLastFirst[i].first[0] &&
arrayLastFirst[i].first[1] == arrayLastFirst[i].last[0] &&  
arrayLastFirst[i].last[1]
```

means that you want

- element 0 of *first* to be not null
- AND element 1 of *last* to be not null
- AND element 1 of *first* to be equal to element 0 of *last*.

This leads to this array:

```
array == [[5, 6], [6, 7]];
```

Comment: you misunderstand me, i guess, couse i want something else :)

Comment: Of course I wasn't saying you wanted _that_, but just that your condition leaded to _that_. Give us a short example with numbers of an input and the expected output. We will give you the condition you need.

Comment: tnx for your answare, i was abel to solve it finally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to put a loop inside a loop.
so you grab the first you want to compare and cycle thru the whole array keeping in mind not to match it with itself. than you grab the second and compare it to the whole array etc.

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayLastFirst.length; i++) {
  for (f = arrayLastFirst.length; f++ {
      if( arrayLastFirst[0][i] == arraLastFirst[0][f] || 
           arrayLastFirst[0][i]== arrayLastfirst[0][f] )

}}
```

edit: sorry for bad code getting used to stackoverflow still this doesnt check 
you can put  if i == i in there to prevent comparing to itself

Comment: Maybe you can make example or something?

Comment: no i need something else, i need to get values, not if the array value inside an object is eqal with another value from another object Example : first value from object1 is eal with last value from object3 , i need that

Comment: do you want to order them or just find the two arrays that match by checking the last value with the first value ? and im guessing you only want them if they match in the order that they appear?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var sources = [
  {
    first: [ 23.53521729574, 58.94867816392],
    last:  [ 24.5368636,     59.9483547    ]
  },
  {
    first: [ 24.53521729574, 59.94867816392],
    last:  [ 23.5368636,     58.9483547    ]
  },
  {
    first: [ 23.5368636, 58.9483547],
    last:  [ 23.5368636, 58.9483547]
  }, 
  {
    first: [ 23.53521729574, 58.9483547],
    last:  [ 23.5368636,     58.9483547]
  }, 
  {
    first: [ 23.5368636, 58.9483547],
    last:  [ 23.5368636, 58.9483547]
  }, 
  {
    first: [ 23.53521729574, 58.9483547],
    last:  [ 23.5368636,     58.9483547]
  }, 
  {
    first: [ 23.53521729574, 58.9483547],
    last:  [ 23.5368636,     58.9483547]
  }
];
var results = {};
for(var z in sources) {
    var sz = sources[z];
    if(!results[sz.last]) {
        results[sz.last] = {keys:[],similar:[]}
    }   
    results[sz.last].keys.push(sz); // add all to .keys anything with same .last

}
for(var z in sources) {
    var sz = sources[z];
    var exists = results[sz.first];
    if(exists) {
        exists.similar.push(sz); // add all to .similar anything with same .first
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(results,null,2))
```

Result:

```
{
  "24.5368636,59.9483547": {
    "keys": [
      {
        "first": [
          23.53521729574,
          58.94867816392
        ],
        "last": [
          24.5368636,
          59.9483547
        ]
      }
    ],
    "similar": []
  },
  "23.5368636,58.9483547": {
    "keys": [
      {
        "first": [
          24.53521729574,
          59.94867816392
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      },
      {
        "first": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      },
      {
        "first": [
          23.53521729574,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      },
      {
        "first": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      },
      {
        "first": [
          23.53521729574,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      },
      {
        "first": [
          23.53521729574,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      }
    ],
    "similar": [
      {
        "first": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      },
      {
        "first": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ],
        "last": [
          23.5368636,
          58.9483547
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: allmoust, but i need to get similar values into  array[ ], and next similar values on the same way, example if i have 3 similar values, if the first object has a value first equals to third object last value the they will be pushed to same array. like object one has a value {first:[23.5368636,
      58.9483547],(same value but from another object, it could be from object 98 and so)},{again simlar values}

Comment: just explain with `{first:bla,last:bla}` changed into simpler term such as `A`, `B`, `C`.. no one here understand what you mean by similar (aka duplicate as you stated on comment 6 hours ago)

Comment: okey, i try my best, i wont complain, tnx for the help and im very glad.   example: array{first:a,last:b},{first:b,last:c},{first:b,last:d};They are cord nodes, and i need to get them to array {[{first:a,last:b},{first:b,last:c},{first:b,last:d}],[and so on ]};

Comment: see the updated answer, if there are many `last:b`, I combine it, for example `[{first:a,last:b},{first:x,last:b},{first:b,last:c}]' would be: {b:{keys:[{first:a,last:b},{first:x,last:b}],values:[{first:b,last:c}], c:{keys:{first:b,last:c},values:[]}}`